# taskkill for particular user

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

how can i kill multiple task of same user we are using this two codes

Code no1

```
@ECHO OFF

TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe
cls
Echo "Please Specify the User ID"

Set /p u=
set USER=%u%@%userdomain%


Echo "Please Specify the PASSWORD"
runas /user:%USER% Explorer.exe
cls

echo "Press any key to Switch Back to Default USer Profile"
Pause
Echo "please enter your password again for verification"
runas /user:%USER% C:\switch.bat
pause
cls
start %windir%\explorer.exe
exit
```

Code no2 (this File name Switch.bat)

```
@echo off

TASKKILL /F /IM Explorer.exe

exit
```

Actually the general idea behind to create this it switches in win XP like win 7 without logging off
Issue is when it switch back to original profile 
all the task of the second user doesnt stop

is that any way to stop all task for a specific user which are running

Comment: I want to kill all process that are open by other users

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `tskill` . It can kill a process and accepts as parameter the user ID:

Kill explorer for the same user

```
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set exe_name=Explorer
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%S in ('query user') do (
            set "current_user=%%S"

            if "!current_user:~0,1!" EQU ">" (
                    for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%M  in ('tasklist ^| find ^"%exe_name%^"') do (
                            tskill "%%M"    /ID:%%U
                    )

            )
    )
    endlocal
    goto :eof
```

For all other users:

```
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set exe_name=Explorer
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%S in ('query user') do (
                set "current_user=%%S"

                if "!current_user:~0,1!" NEQ ">" (
                        for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%M  in ('tasklist ^| find ^"%exe_name%^"') do (
                                tskill "%%M"    /ID:%%U
                        )

                )
        )
        endlocal
        goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kill all processes of a particular user like this (provided you have admin privileges):

```
@echo off
taskkill /fi "username eq %1" /t /f
```

Run the script like this:

```
C:\>script.cmd joe
```

However, why don't you simply log the second user off instead of switching back? That would be the obvious (and much cleaner) solution. As admin you can even log off other users on the commandline:

```
logoff session
```

You can enumerate the sessions with `query session` (or `qwinsta` if the former doesn't work):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3" %%s in ('qwinsta ^| find /i "joe"') do (
  logoff %%s
)
```